# IntelliJ not removing classes after manual deletion

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on an IntelliJ Java project. I'm trying to remove a class, so I right click it in the pane on the left and click delete (without safe delete). However, in my other classes, I'm still referencing the deleted class, and there is no error. The project builds and runs as normal.

I've tried finding a .class file for this class in Finder and deleting it, but this hasn't worked. I tried rebuilding and cleaning my project but this hasn't worked.

I expect the class to not be able to be resolved in my other files, but it is still being resolved.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can try : `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: Likely a project configuration issue. If Gautam's suggestion to invalidate your caches did not work, you'll need to provide more info as CrazyCoder suggests.

Comment: @WhoopsBing, what do you mean by "hasn't worked"?  But I confirm your observation, IDEA does not delete .class files when a .kt file is deleted in a standard Maven + Kotlin project.  IMHO that's quite important feature.